# Awning window portable AC

Tags: windows, portable-ac

I live in a pretty old condo in PNW with an awning window. We had a few days of very hot summer, but it is mostly cool. Due to how my condo unit is, I can't install a window AC. Portable AC is ok.

I went through another post that suggested installing a piece of plexiglass and cut out a hole in that to allow for the portable AC vent. I'm not sure how to go about it honestly. Should I drill a whole in the window frame & screw the plexiglass on or install it using some sort of glue?

I tried using 3M double sided tape and cardboard to try to hold the AC pipe, but it wouldn't stick. You can see the remnants of the 3M tape around the window.

Ideally I want to be able to remove the plexiglass, since it doesn't get too hot most days of summer. My ideal case would be to drill and have plastic anchors, so that I can screw on the plexiglass when needed.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Drilling into the window frame for _any_ purpose will likely get your damage deposit withheld as a down payment on a window replacement. It may well cause your window to leak cold air, if not water, right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a shape (see below) that would fit the opening. I would use insulating foam board and maybe put self-adhesive weather strip along the edges. the bottom piece need only be large enough to accommodate a hole large enough to put the AC exhaust hose through. No need for Plexiglas (which is much harder to work with than foam, or even plywood or "1x" boards) with this design because the view/light would be barely affected/blocked. If the awning pane does not support itself in the desired open position, fashion a stick-arm to prop it open in the position you need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify what material the side part should be? And how should the side part be fixed to the lower part (the hole is in the lower part)? Also do you see any problems in drilling the window?

Comment: If it were me I would try to use insulating foam board, with the panels attached using hot-melt glue gun, perhaps reinforced with angle brackets. This could be painted if needed. I don't see that the window would need drilling unless for some small screws to fashion a "hold-open arm" if needed. I would avoid drilling the pane for fear of compromising it somehow (e.g., affecting the seal, cracking the glass lite, etc.) Some self-adhesive weatherstrip around the perimeter would seal out drafts, as mentioned in my answer. Alternatively, should be easy to make with plywood.

Comment: Attach the weather stripping to the add-in piece, not the window frame. That limits the amount of glue that must be removed from the frame when you move out, reducing the change that the landlord will ding your damage deposit for this.